# Add a column to quote item table

Tags: magento-1.7, database, quote, setup-script, column

I want to add a column to the `sales_flat_quote_item` (and `..._order_item`) table through an install script, but when I go to the table `sales_flat_quote_item` (or `..._order_item`) in my database - the column is not there.

The install script's version is 0.0.1. My `config.xml` is also 0.0.1.

I have cleared the cache. I refreshed the back-end, so the script has ran.

Any clues?

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote_item'), 'print_sku', "varchar NOT NULL");
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order_item'), 'print_sku', "varchar NOT NULL");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to add column to `sales_flat_quote_item` you will have to write an upgrade script for that follow below steps.

1. Create a module or use your existing custom module.
2. Modify your `config.xml` to add a setup resource with class `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup`:

   ```
   <global>
       <resources>
           <your_module_setup>
               <setup>
                   <module>Your_Module</module>
                   <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
               </setup>
          </your_module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
   ```
3. Create a directory `data/your_module_setup` in your module
4. Create a `data-install` or `data-upgrade` script containing the following code:

   ```
   $installer = $this;

   $installer->startSetup();

   $installer->addAttribute(
       'quote_item',  /* order, quote, order_item, quote_item */
       'your_attribute_code', 
       array(
           'type' => 'varchar', /* int, varchar, text, decimal, datetime */
           'nullable' => false, /* default true */
           'grid' => false, /* or true if you wan't use this attribute on orders grid page */
       )
   );

   $installer->endSetup();
   ```

Comment: I used my code for the script, but you gave me the idea to add the code in my `config.xml`. I didn't know I have to do that also. Thanks.