# Customization of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items_Grid

Tags: orders, grid, sales, admin-panel, items

I want to add a custom 'gift wrap' column under 'Items Ordered' so that I can add gift wrapping cost to the subtotal of the product. The page is present at `admin panel->sales->orders->create new order->create new customer`. The file to this page is present at (app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Create\Items\Grid.php) Please find the screen shot of what I intend to do. I am unable to do this,please help[image: before][image: after]

Answer (score 3):

This is the similar work I am just doing now.

You will need to change/overwrite following file:

`design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml`

[Learn how to override template](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-overriding-template-file-from-custom-module/):

Basically you are adding `<th>` in `<thead>` and `<td>` in `<tbody>` section.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

In that file

add `<col width="80" />` in **`<col>`** section.

and change

```
<thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                    <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Product') ?></th>
                    <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Price') ?></th>
                    <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Qty') ?></th>
                    <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
                    <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Discount') ?></th>
                    <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Row Subtotal') ?></th>

                    <th class="no-link last"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Action') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

To

```
         <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
                <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Product') ?></th>
                <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Price') ?></th>
                <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Qty') ?></th>
                <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Gift wrap') ?></th>
                <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
                <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Discount') ?></th>
                <th class="no-link"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Row Subtotal') ?></th>

                <th class="no-link last"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Action') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

and change

```
 <td><input name="item[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" class="input-text item-qty" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" maxlength="12" /></td>
```

to

```
<td><input name="item[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" class="input-text item-qty" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" maxlength="12" /></td>
<td><input name="item[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][gift_wrap]" class="input-text item-gift-wrap" value="<?php echo $_item->getGiftWrap() ?>" /></td>
```

**Important**

`echo $_item->getGiftWrap()` is coming from database table `sales_flat_quote_item`, so you must have a column named `gift_wrap`.

You can add that column like this (in your setup/sql file)

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_flat_quote_item'),
        'gift_wrap',
        array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Gift Wrap'
        )
    );
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Can u please share the edits in the file when you are done. I need this to be done urgently

Comment: My file will not match with your, since I am doing other stuff, but file is same. Also see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks a ton! I am new to magento,so I may need your further guidance If I am stuck.

Comment: should I follow [these](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12931/add-a-column-to-quote-item-table) steps to add column

Comment: Yes, but you should add exactly my above code in that setup file.