# Custom price attribute on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, price

I am making a rent module and I want to send a price attribute "rent_price" to cart page when customer click on rent button and normal price(base/special) when they click on add to cart.
Please help.

Comment: do you wan to get the rent_price in cart page right ?

Comment: where are add `Rent Button`

Comment: yes I want rent_price used in all the actions that follows like cart, order, payment, invoice etc.

Comment: @AmitBera Rent Button is a custom button I will add on product page!

Comment: Please take your time to accept an anser it it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edited:

1. add New Action (rentAction) to CartContoller.php and Copy code of
   addAction to this new Action
2. add New field (from_rent) to sales_quote_item which define a cart is
   doing from rent button

See [Add a column to quote item table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12931/add-a-column-to-quote-item-table)

1. then using checkout_cart_product_add_after set  from_rent=1  using
   current request Action

See how use this event http://doghouse.agency/article/magento-adding-message-product-during-purchase

```
public function addrentFlag(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        try {

            $Event = $observer->getEvent();
                $product=$Event->getProduct();
                $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
                $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );
                if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName()=='rent'):
                $item->setFromRent(1);
            endif;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // log any issues, but allow system to continue.

            mage::logException($e);
            if (mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

a.you can use magento [`event/observer`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).
Basically  there are two events,by which you can change the cart price of that products:

1. `checkout_cart_product_add_after`
2. `checkout_cart_update_items_after`
3. `checkout_cart_product_update_after`

This 3 event is need because of:

### Event1:checkout_cart_product_add_after

This event is fire when `first time a product is cart for current session` of current input values from frontend

### Event2:checkout_cart_product_update_after

This event is fire when `a current exiting cart item` edited from  **edit** link  of  cart item.

### Event3:checkout_cart_update_items_after

This event is fire whenever cart items update from cart page.

**As per as magento system,** a `cart item price` change using `setter` functions `setCustomPrice(), setOriginalCustomPrice` of cart item Object.

**Just like:**

```
$EachCartitem->setCustomPrice($price);
$EachCartitem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
// Enable super mode on the product.
$EachCartitem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

And using `events fire an observer` which is `calculate price basic of your your rend field`.

![enter image description here][2]

**Config.xml code like:**

```
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento65569>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento65569_Model</class>
      </magento65569>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_cart_product_add_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65569/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>CalculatePrice</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
      <checkout_cart_update_items_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_update_items_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65569/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>UpdateCalculatePrice</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </checkout_cart_update_items_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
        <checkout_cart_product_update_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_product_update_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65569/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>ExitingcartItemUpdate</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </checkout_cart_product_update_after_handler>
        </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_update_after>
            </events>
  </global>
```

**Observer code like this:**

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento65569_Model_Observer
{

        /* This function will work when product will cart */ 
            public function CalculatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                //Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
                $RadioVal=0;
                $TextVal=0;
                $resultParams=array();
                $Event = $observer->getEvent();
                $product=$Event->getProduct();
                $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
                $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );
            $price=$product->getData('rent_price');
                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            return;

            }
            /*  This function will work when cart item  will   qty  update */
            public function UpdateCalculatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
                 // Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_before', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
                 $cart=$observer->getEvent()->getCart();
                 $data=$observer->getEvent()->getInfo();
                 foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
                        $quote_item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
                    if (!$quote_item) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );
                    $price=$product->getData('rent_price');
                        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                    // Enable super mode on the product.
                    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                 }


            }
            public function ExitingcartItemUpdate($observer){
              /*Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_update_after', array(
                        'quote_item' => $result,
                        'product' => $product
                    ));*/
                $Event = $observer->getEvent();
                $product=$Event->getProduct();
            $price=$product->getData('rent_price');
                $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
                $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );

                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);


                return
            }






}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom option "rent" (type: checkbox, required: no) and set the difference as price for the option. Custom option prices can be negative, so having a lower rent price is not a problem.

You also don't need your rent_price attribute anymore with this approach.